# Mutating/Reading a HashMap from multiple threads but one thread at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, memory-barriers

I want to use a LinkedHashMap in a multi-threaded environment, where multiple threads can access the hashmap (read/write), but only one thread will do so at one time. Hence synchronization is not required. But, I need to ensure that the changes done by one thread are readable by any other thread which accesses it later.
For example:

```
    LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap();
    // Thread 1 
    map.put(key1, val1);

    // Thread 2. It starts after thread 1 has finished.
    Object val = map.get(key1);
    assert(val == val1);
```

..edit

Some people wanted the question to be explicitly stated. So here it is:

"I want to ensure that the changes done to a LinkedHashMap are visible to other threads i.e the changes are written to the main memory, and other threads read the map from main memory only. There is no concurrent access of the map."

Comment: If you are using java7 or greater then you may use ConcurrentHahsMap - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: i dont see a question here. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: It will simply work. You don't need to do anything special if everything you described is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how exactly you enforce "only one thread will access the map at one time". (The naive understanding of time is inapplicable here. Synchronization is what gives the meaning to time in programs). If you are piggybacking on external synchronization anywhere else, then it's probably work, albeit in a fragile way.

> "I want to ensure that the changes done to a LinkedHashMap are visible
>   to other threads i.e the changes are written to the main memory, and
>   other threads read the map from main memory only."

Then you **have** to use synchronization. Nothing else will get you the semantics you are asking for. Guarding all accesses with `synchronized` on the same object is a routine way, but that penalizes the reads. It might be more performant to guard the `LinkedHashMap` accesses with `ReadWriteLock`, if reads greatly outnumber the writes.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am having another external synchronization scheme. It is sort of (but not exactly) like this:
1) Thread 1 does updates to the map. It pushes a notification into a BlockingQueue.
2) Thread 2 receives the notification from the queue, and then reads the map

Comment: That should work, since as per Javadoc: "Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a BlockingQueue happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the BlockingQueue in another thread."

Comment: Thanks, this should work. Marking the last comment as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ConcurrentHashMap. It scans for a node containing given key while trying to acquire lock, creating and returning one if not found. Upon return, guarantees that lock is held.

### Example:

```
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    concurrentMap.put("key", "value");
    String value = concurrentMap.get("key");
```

Comment: I actually want to use a LinkedHashMap which in my knowledge does not come with a Concurrent version. Also, using a ConcurrentHashMap might degrade the performance. Can you please provide more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of inter-thread visibilty, you still need to use some facility which will ensure `happens-before` relationship ([JLS7 Section 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)) between write to a map and subsequent reads from other threads. Simplest way is your olde `synchronized` block:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
...
synchronized(lock) {
     // write to map
}
...
synchronized(lock) {
     // read from map
}
```

Or, maybe, at least one of following conditions applies to your code, so you won't need `synchronized`:

- A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
- All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.

E.g., your writer starts reader after a write, or reader calls `writer.join()` before doing its' read.